# Change View Swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

the swift code below represents two views the first that is displayed is home with the login button and the register button, what I have to do is that when the SIGNUP button is clicked the push to the HomeView view which contains the MapView, practically I have to push to the new view with the click on signup, but with the navigationlink this does not show me the view, how do I solve this?

**Home.Swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit


struct HomeView:  View {
    @State private var userTrackingMode: MapUserTrackingMode = .follow
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 25.7617,
            longitude: 80.1918
        ),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(
            latitudeDelta: 10,
            longitudeDelta: 10
        )
    )

    var body: some View {
        Map(
            coordinateRegion: $region,
            interactionModes: MapInteractionModes.all,
            showsUserLocation: true,
            userTrackingMode: $userTrackingMode
        )
        
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

**ContectView.Swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("Color"), Color("Color1"), Color("Color2")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            if UIScreen.main.bounds.height > 800 {

                Home()
            }
            else {

                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

                    Home()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Home: View {

    @State var index = 0
    @State var showingDetail = false
    @State var isModal: Bool = false



    func login() {

    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 180)

            HStack {

                Button(action: {

                    withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.8, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: 0.5)) {

                        self.index = 0
                    }


                }) {

                    Text("Login")
                        .foregroundColor(self.index == 0 ? .black : .white)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50) / 2).sheet(isPresented: $isModal, content: {

                    })

                }.background(self.index == 0 ? Color.white : Color.clear)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())

                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.8, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: 0.5)) {

                        self.index = 1
                    }

                }) {

                    Text("New User")
                        .foregroundColor(self.index == 1 ? .black : .white)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50) / 2)

                }.background(self.index == 1 ? Color.white : Color.clear)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())

            }.background(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .padding(.top, 25)

            if self.index == 0 {

                Login(mail: "", pass: "", areYouGoingToSecondView: false)

            }
            else {

                SignUp()
            }

            if self.index == 0 {

                Button(action: {

                }) {

                    Text("Forget Password?")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)

                }
                    .padding(.top, 20)
            }

        }
            .padding()
    }
}

struct Login: View {

    @State var mail = ""
    @State var pass = ""
    @State var areYouGoingToSecondView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            VStack {

                HStack(spacing: 15) {

                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)

                    TextField("Enter Email Address", text: self.$mail)

                }.padding(.vertical, 20)

                Divider()

                HStack(spacing: 15) {

                    Image(systemName: "lock")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)

                    SecureField("Password", text: self.$pass)

                    Button(action: {

                    }) {

                        Image(systemName: "eye")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }

                }.padding(.vertical, 20)

            }
                .padding(.vertical)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.top, 25)



            Button(action: {
                print("Prova di stampa")
            }) {

                Text("LOGIN")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)


            }.background(

                LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("Color2"), Color("Color1"), Color("Color")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            )
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .offset(y: -40)
                .padding(.bottom, -40)
                .shadow(radius: 15)
        }
    }
}

struct SignUp: View {

    @State var mail = ""
    @State var pass = ""
    @State var checkpass = ""
    @State var repass = ""
    @State var name = ""
    @State var surname = ""

    func signup() -> Bool {
      print("Sono in signup")
        /*let u = User(email: self.mail, name: self.name, password: self.pass, surname: self.surname)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), execute: {

                u.register(completion: { result in
                    
                    print("\n Risultato:")
                    print(result)
                }
                )
            }
        )*/
    
      
        
        NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()) {
                           Text("Show Detail View")
                       }

            return true
        }

        var body: some View {

            VStack {

                VStack {

                    HStack(spacing: 15) {

                        Image(systemName: "envelope")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)

                        TextField("Enter Email Address", text: self.$mail)

                    }.padding(.vertical, 20)

                    Divider()

                    HStack(spacing: 15) {

                        Image(systemName: "person")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)

                        TextField("Enter Name", text: self.$name)



                    }.padding(.vertical, 20)


                    Divider()

                    HStack(spacing: 15) {

                        Image(systemName: "person")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)

                        TextField("Enter Surname", text: self.$surname)



                    }.padding(.vertical, 20)



                    HStack(spacing: 15) {

                        Image(systemName: "lock")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)

                        SecureField("Password", text: self.$pass)

                        Button(action: {

                        }) {

                            Image(systemName: "eye")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }

                    }.padding(.vertical, 20)

                    Divider()
                    HStack(spacing: 15) {

                        Image(systemName: "lock")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)

                        SecureField("Re-Enter Password", text: self.$checkpass)

                        Button(action: {

                        }) {

                            Image(systemName: "eye")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }

                    }.padding(.vertical, 20)


                }
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.top, 25)


              
                //Button for signup user
                Button(action: {
                   
                    signup()
                    
                }) {

                    Text("SIGNUP")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.vertical)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)

                }.background(

                    LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("Color2"), Color("Color1"), Color("Color")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                )
                
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .offset(y: -40)
                    .padding(.bottom, -40)
                    .shadow(radius: 15)
                }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, can you only share relevant code related to issue, instead of  every class ? Also navigationLink will work only with navigationView, and inside “body” property of view. Which you aren’t doing.

Comment: As @TusharSharma said NavigationLink only works inside a NavigationView. You need to 1. add a NavigationView inside the `body`, and 2. move the NavigationLink there